# Is a DVD sensor a photodiode or an array of them?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, photodiode, phototransistor

Is a DVD sensor **just** a *photodiode* or an array of them?

I need to know if it is a CMOS with an array of them or just a single sensor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signal is picked up with a high-speed photodiode array of several sensors to allow the tracking circuitry and focusing to work. Using closed-loop control allows the mechanical parts to have relatively loose tolerances compared to even an LP record turntable. As one Japanese Engineer said you could make the player chassis out of chopsticks and it would still work.

[image: http://www.ocj.co.jp/english/products/lightpickup_fm/lightpickup_fm.htm]

Here's the sensor array used in a [Sony](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/sony/a6802588.pdf) pickup:

[image]

Comment: Nice, do you know if the quad in the center (A,B,C,D) are used to keep the beam centered?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I think E and F are the tracking, and A..D are the signal and focus (using an astigmatic lens). This looks like a pretty good description here (there's a diffraction grating in there): http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen180/LN/optical.html

Comment: That's nice. Thanks.  The focus error signal is (A+C)-(B+D). I'm picturing the off-axis crescent/coma type images, but that may not be the right error.  The 1/4 wave plate-polarizer combo  to look at the reflected signal is new to me.  I was just doing a workshop this week and showing how to use the pair as a "poor man's optical isolator" to block reflections.  I'd never thought to look at the reflected signal!